# Getting started with git

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, git, github

I want to use git to version control files in a new project. I have read an overview of git, but it is not clear to me if git hosts the code for you.

I do not want my code to be hosted on a third party computer. I want to be able to host my files on a computer in my internal network, with no chance of the code being stored on a third party server.

How may I set up a repository on my local machine?
Do I need to do anything extra to prevent github uploading my files to http://github.com?

Comment: Git and GitHub are not the same thing, though it sounds to me like that's what you're thinking. Git is the version control program, GitHub is a company that specializes in hosting Git repositories.

Comment: Suggested an edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: You might also want to add a tag indicating what platform/OS you are working on. Git on Windows for example is not a particularly easy fit, personally I find [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) easier to work with on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub is of no use to you if you need to keep your code secret since you are putting the code onto their servers. However, with a paid subscription, you can create "private" projects. The code is still on their servers but only the people you give access to can see it (and any unscrupulous GitHub employees of course since the data is not encrypted by you - though I'm sure that this is very unlikely).

In either case, you still *work* with the code locally. You check (pull, clone, etc)a copy of the code out to your development machine, make your changes and then push them back to the GitHub copy.

By the sound of it, you don't need or want anything from GitHub, just from [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Once you have installed git and done the recommended basic configuration. Create a folder for your project and type:

```
git init
```

at the command line. The git documentation is pretty reasonable and explains all the basics.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is just [git](http://git-scm.com/). You will install a git repository on your server, and use git client software on your development computers. Github is a service that hosts git repositories and code for you, which is not what you want.